# Entity FrameWork защита от SQL инъекций

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-injection

Начал изучать Entity FrameWork под .Net MVC, реализую DB First-то бишь есть готовая база Mysql и с помощью EF создаю сущности `DBContext` и т.д.(таблицы в классы).

Возникают вопросы, как защититься от sql injections при запросах к базе? На подобии  PDO в php , например, как сделать выборку с параметром WHERE, где значение, пришедшее с клиента по http запросу -будет экранированное!Нужно защититься от инъекций! Классический пример `;1=1` и т.д.

Comment: Так EF сам об этом заботится и сам строит запросы. Вы работаете не с таблицами напрямую, а с их сущностями, сделать выборку с `WHERE` просто через `linq` `var data = db.MyTable.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();`

Answer (score 3):

EF использует параметризированные запросы, что исключает инъекции через кривые значения параметров.

Основной путь появления SQL инъекций - это вписывание значений параметров прямо в тело запроса (классический `1=1`) срабатывает так:

- Вы получаете от клиента по HTTP значение (`' OR 1=1 --`)
- В коде на бэке вы вписываете прямо в тело запроса и получаете там `NAME = '' OR 1=1...`
- SQL разбирает запрос, видит в нем условие на Name и проверку 1=1, выполняет код именно так, как написано в запросе - возвращает все строки злоумышленнику.

В SQL Server этот путь чинится параметризацией запросов. В тексте запроса передается только имя параметра, а не его значение (`WHERE Name = @Name`). Сами значения параметров передаются отдельно, и ни в какой момент в текст запроса не вписываются. Ни в сыром виде, ни в экранированном.

SQL Server составляет план выполнения на основе именно текста запроса. Вне зависимости от того, что будет передано ему в качестве параметр `@Name` - он будет фильтровать по колонке Name. `1=1` никак не может выпрыгнуть из значения параметра и влезть в текст запроса. И уже после составления плана ("отфильровать по Name"), в момент выполнения этого плана, при проходе по таблице будет использовано значение параметра, причем только как строка для поиска, а не как булево выражение.

Примерно так же ведет себя PDO в случае не-emulated prepare. Экранирование используется только в emulated режиме (не PHP-разработчик, не уверен, насколько он часто используется). Разница только в том, что в SQL Server prepare и параметризация разделены. Можно параметризировать не-prepared запросы, и наоборот.

EF использует внутри параметризированные запросы, так что протолкнуть через него SQL Injection не получится. Что-то может пойти не так только в случае, когда вы будете дергать через EF свои самописные процедуры SQL, в которых будете клеить динамический SQL из значений параметров. Но EF тут уже ни при чем.

Comment: А можно пример кода с параметризированным запросом?

Comment: @user321474 да, он есть [в справке по SqlCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Parameters)

Comment: Нужен именно пример EF

Comment: @user321474 любой код с where на ef будет использовать параметризацию внутри.

Comment: @user321474 вы, кажется, не поняли сути ответа. В EF не надо делать каких-то дополнительных телодвижений для защиты от инъекций. Нужно просто не работать с SQL вручную. А очень надо работать с чистым SQL - не вклеивать прямо в текст команды значения, которые пришли от конечного пользователя (не добавлять их в текст запроса через +)

Comment: то бишь , если в  EF , то можно влеивать? Можно пример пожалуйста, нормального запроса в EF c WHERE выражением!!!!?

Comment: @user321474 наоборот. вообще никогда вклеивать нельзя. ни в EF, ни в остальных ORM. Пример с where есть в комментариях к вопросу.

Comment: Так там же name в примере вклеин?То бишь в linq ef

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, если я конечно не ошибаюсь, ORM и в частности EF использует уже параметризованные запросы. Во всяком случае, если речь идёт о работе с объектной моделью сущностей.

Другое дело если Вы используете `raw SQL` запросы в том или ином виде. Но, использование SQL в открытом виде в EF нежелательно, т.к. противоречит самой сути подхода ORM. Да и с безопасностью это создаёт серьёзные проблемы.

Дополнительное чтение: [Вопросы безопасности (Entity Framework)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations).

Comment: ORM EF уже использует? По умолчанию? Или в api его есть возможность сделать? Почитав ресурс с ссылки вашей по вопросам безопасности, понял , что помимо sql иньекций, есть еще и иньекция на уровне EF query, то бишь если плохой человек знает , что твое творение на .net в связке с EF, он сможет на уровне EF linq накрутить делов! А как все это обезопасить? Там одни общие фразы!

Comment: Параметрические запросы EF использует уже по умолчанию. Если, конечно Вы не захотите использовать чистый SQL. А, чтобы предотвратить инъекцию, метод защиты довольно простой. Нельзя объединять данные пользователя и  текст запроса. В статье есть ссылка на описание построителя запросов. Вы вполне можете использовать его.

Comment: Нельзя объединять данные пользователя и текст запроса./// а можно пример? Не совсем понятно это выражение.EntityConnectionStringBuilder вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Я имел в виду это: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bb896238(v=vs.100)

Comment: Там же в доках можно найти примеры. Просто у меня сейчас нет под рукой VS.

Comment: А это примеры LINQ к Entities? или Entity SQL? В чем в них разница (+ -)? Сырые запросы, это понятно, а вот по эти двум? Плохо,что примеры из источника на VB, они поленились на C# examples сделать)))?